# Get-Credentials error in PowerShell 'Cannot find an Overload for "PSCredential"'

Tags: powershell

I'm new to PowerShell. I am trying to make it so I can setup a new computer connecting to the network to allow me to do certain tasks. When I run this:

```
$domain = "mydomain.com" 
$mycred = get-credential
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("$($domain)\$($mycred.Username)","$($mycred.Password)")
$compName = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter new computer name"
Add-Computer -DomainName $domain -newname $compName -Credential $credential -Restart
Pause
```

I get the error:

> New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "PSCredential" and the argument count: "2".
> At C:\Users\entername\Downloads\1-JoinDomainCred.ps1:7 char:15
>
> - ... redential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("$($ ...
> - 
> - CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `Get-Credential` aready returns a proper credentials object. Just use that: `$mycred = Get-Credential; Add-Computer ... -Credential $mycred`

Comment: PowerShell is not C#, pass the arguments as an array without the `()`: `$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "$($domain)\$($mycred.Username)",$mycred.Password`

Answer (score 0):

Get-Credential aready returns a proper credentials object. Just use that:

```
 $mycred = Get-Credential; Add-Computer ... -Credential $mycred
```

PowerShell is not C#, pass the arguments as an array without the `()`:

```
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "$($domain)\$($mycred.Username)",$mycred.Password
```